# Merging two text files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, merge

I have two text files. One has the following list in it:

```
dog
cat
horse
```

The other has this:

```
kennel
flap
shoes
```

I want to merge these two text files into a new text file so that the terms are listed beside each other like so:

```
dog kennel
cat flap
horse shoes
```

How would I go about doing this? This is my code so far but it's largely incorrect:

```
f1 = File.readlines('C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\hat.txt')
f2 = File.readlines('C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\sat.txt')

File.open('file3.txt','w') do |output_file|

    f1.zip(f2) do |a,b|
        output_file.puts f1,f2
    end

end
```

Comment: What are `f1`, `f2`?

Comment: ahh my mistake, i've edited it. it should make sense. so currently it just seems to print everything as a list rather than beside one another. Is there anyway of making the lists beside one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# get the data
f1 = File.readlines('./text1.txt')
f2 = File.readlines('./text2.txt')

# remove the newlines
f1 = f1.map {|elem| elem.chomp}
f2 = f2.map {|elem| elem.chomp}

File.open('file3.txt', 'w') do |output_file|
  #enumerate over the array length (take advantage of same size for both arrays)
  f1.each_with_index do |elem, i|

  # output the string interpolation
  output_file.puts "#{elem} #{f2[i]}"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
output_file.puts f1, f2
```

do

```
output_file.puts "#{a.chomp} #{b}"
```

Comment: I get the following error:   C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/test2:19:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `chomp' for ["dog\n", "cat\n", "horse"]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: This as well as the other users codes worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Merging Within a Block Closure, Plus Return Values

You can use the block syntax for [File#open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html#method-c-open) to create a closure for a method chain that handles the merging. Within the innermost block, you can take advantage of the fact that [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) will iterate over a collection such as an array of lines, and that format-string interpolation will accept an array argument as well. For example:

```
File.open('f3', ?w) do |f3|
  File.readlines('f1').
    zip(File.readlines 'f2').
    flat_map { |arr| ln = sprintf "%s %s\n" % arr.map(&:chomp); f3.print ln; ln }
end
#=> ["dog kennel\n", "cat flap\n", "horse shoes\n"]
```

Not only will this now give you a useful return value, but it will also correctly merge files f1 and f2 into a new file named f3. Given your corpus, this file will contain:

> dog kennel
>      cat flap
>      horse shoes

In addition, this code will also handle files with more than one word per line in each file. If f1 contains "big dog" and f2 contains "shoes and hand grenades", this code will Do The Right Thing™ and return:

```
#=> ["big dog kennel\n", "cat flap\n", "horse shoes and hand grenades\n"]
```

This code may be overly-clever at the expense of readability, but shows off a number of useful Ruby features (most especially the utility of return values) that you or others may find helpful. There's always more than one way to do things in Ruby, and sometimes compact, expressive code is what's needed. Your mileage may vary.